# Visual Studio/Crystal Reports dataset - SELECT * FROM tableHERE WHERE user_id = varHere?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report in my Visual Studio (aspx and C#) website. I created a DataSet, and it works fine. It grabs all data from a table and displays on a report.

I want to have another report that shows only one row of the table based on what the user selects. It will be a specific user id that they select. I am not sure how to program my DataSet to have this user input.

I know it'll be `SELECT * FROM tableHERE WHERE user_id = varHere`, but how can I put in a variable with a DataSet and have it work with my application?

The working code for my first DataSet is the following:

```
SELECT registrant.*, event_id AS Expr1
FROM     registrant
WHERE  (event_id = 1)
```

Basically I want this same thing, but I want to add `WHERE (event_id = 1) AND registrant_id = USER_INPUT`

Comment: Create a parameter and use that parameter in the record selection formula.

Comment: Okay how do I do that? I'm in the query builder and do not see that option.